# Stuck in loop when user input a letter

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble making input validation for numeric input only. Below is my code it loops every time I input a letter, inputting the wrong number doesn't though. It loops "Invalid Input, please try again." and the only option is to close it. How can i fix this?

```
        while (!(cin >> userOption) || userOption < 1 || userOption > 12) {
            cout << "Invalid Input, please try again." << endl;
            cin >> userOption;
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cin.clear();
```

Comment: Why is there `cin>>userOption` both in the condition and in the loop body? Remove it from the body.

Comment: You forgot to use a "default" branch for your switch operator

Comment: `case 12` has unreachable code.

Comment: @fiscblog - you mean the `break`? True. But I've seen linters and compilers that warn if the `break;` is missing, even if it's unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want `cin >> userOption` both in the `while` condition and inside the loop, as that makes two inputs per loop.

The one in the `while` condition should be enough.

Comment: That's only half the truth. `userOption` should be initialized, that's why user2882555 put it inside the condition.

Comment: @fiscblog : molbdnilo is saying to keep the 'cin >> userOption' which does the initialization, and ditch the one in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to break out of the loop if result is OK:

```
    while (true) {
       if (!(cin >> userOption) || (userOption_tmp < 1) || (userOption_tmp > 12)) {
        cout << "Invalid Input, please try again." << endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
       }
       else {
             break;
       }

        //this is looping when letter inputed
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, (cin >> userOption) should be inside the if. Fixed.

Comment: Sry, my bad removed my extra `cin >> userOption` also:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all initialize `userOption`:

```
unsigned int userOption = 0;
```

Then go like this:

```
while ( userOption < 1 || userOption > 12 /* or even true, like Atle suggested */) 
{
     cin >> userOption;
     if( !cin || userOption < 1 || userOption > 12 )
     {
         cout << "Invalid Input, please try again." << endl;
         std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
         std::cin.clear();
         continue;
      }
      else
         break;  //this is looping when letter inputed
 }
```

Comment: You only need to initialize it because you removed the wrong `cin >> userOption)`.